# What is the document root of a JavaEE Application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

This is from the [Java EE6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html):

> A web module has a specific structure. The top-level directory of a
>   web module is the document root of the application. The document root
>   is where XHTML pages, client-side classes and archives, and static web
>   resources, such as images, are stored.
>
> **The document root contains a subdirectory named WEB-INF**, which can
>   contain the following files and directories

But in [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/), it seems like the WEB-INF directory is not the **document root.** Also when you create a JSF Project using NetBeans, the folder structure will be like:

```
ProjectName
|
|
--src
|
|
--web
   |
   |
   --WEB-INF
```

which means the web directory again is not the document root?

So which is correct?

Because in Java EE6 Tutorial, the text continues:

> **The document root contains a subdirectory named WEB-INF**, which can
>   contain the following files and directories classes: A directory that contains 
>   server side classes: servlets, enterprise bean class files, utility classes,
>   JavaBeanscomponents

But according to Netbeans, and the tutorial above, server side classes are in a different directory?

Help with this confusion please?

Comment: If you check the tutorial there, it tells you that it will use maven, that's why the folder structure is different. Please refer to http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/

Comment: Netbeans does not use maven, still different structure.

Comment: The term *web module* doesn't refer to anything related to NetBeans project structure. The tutorial you linked to it explains that! A web module is just "something you can deploy to an appserver". In your case, the contents of the `web` directory. What the tutorial says is that the *web module* is the directory that contains `WEB-INF`.

Comment: @millimoose The contents of the web directory? What happens to everything in src directory?

Comment: @KorayTugay It gets compiled and added to `WEB-INF/classes` or maybe as a `.jar` into `WEB-INF/lib`. You don't really deploy Java sources.

Comment: In order to follow this tutorial you should first learn the basic concepts of [maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This question is really not about maven. Thanks.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Why are you going on about Maven? This is a conceptual question about Java EE, not a question about project setup / building.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I did read the tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Still false. The same basic "unintuitive" thing happens in both a NetBeans and a Maven project.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The same result being..?

Comment: @KorayTugay the jar, war or the artifact that your project will produce.

Comment: @KorayTugay Anyway, in both the Java EE tutorial and the JSF blog post what goes on is that some things (library `.jar`s and your project's compiled `.class` files) get added to the files in the `web` (or `webapp`) directory at some point. (Before deployment, or before the appserver is launched, or before a `.war` archive is created.) So in a way neither of those is really a web module, but they contain some of the files that make up one.

Comment: @millimoose Thanks. But your answer does not 100% match with Surge 's answer? I am a bit confused? Are these files moved under the WEB-INF file in my project setup, then compiled? Or Is that Web-Inf directory mentioned in the Java EE Tutorial a whole different Web-Inf directory?

Comment: @KorayTugay I'd say it's because even I usually think of the `webapp` folder in maven projects as "the web module, **except** Java code, **except** library files, because Maven will add those there for me". It's not insofar as you can't copy that directory from your project to an appserver and have it work (you need to build a WAR or assemble a "real" web module or do something ugly to an appserver's configuration), but it intuitively seems like one insofar as it contains all the "webby" bits of a project, as opposed to the "Java-ey" ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The EE spec talks about the directory structure of your final war file. The directory structure you put in your question is how IDE arranges different files in its project structure. They are two different things.

To answer your question, the document root in the war is the parent directory of WEB-INF directory. Different IDE has different document root for the project structure, but in most cases, it is the parent directory of WEB-INF directory too. In the netbeans case, it is the `web` folder. In the standard Eclipse web project, it is the `WebContent` directory. In the maven world, it is the `src/main/webapp` directory. These are all configurable though in the IDE.

Comment: So the Web-Inf directory I have has nothing to do with the Web-Inf directory Java EE mentions about? Because my class files are under the src file, whereas JavaEE says that class files are under the Web-Inf directory? That is the Web-Inf in the final war file, not the Web-Inf in my project setup?

Comment: Your source .java file are in the src directory. But after you generate your war file, the compiled .class file will end up in the WEB-INF/classes directory. The WEB-INF directory in our project is linked to the WEB-INF directory in your final war, but they are not the same. There are lots of copy/zip happen during the compilation/package phase of your development

Comment: As the answer points out--there's the coding step, where files are arranged however you, the IDE, and the build system prefers, and there's the deployment step, where the build system assembles a .war and you deploy it.  The document root is the root of the .war, and it contains the WEB-INF directory. In your coding IDE, the document root is wherever the build system says it is, e.g. web, or WebContent, or src/main/webapp.

Comment: @JerryAndrews Thanks. It is very clear now. I was confused reading the tutorial because of the names being exactly identical. ( Names of the folders. )